# Prevent the browser to jump to anchors

Tags: javascript, mootools, anchor

How can I prevent the browser from jumping to anchor links?

I know that I can user "return false" on the onclick event or if someone is using mootools do something like this

```
$('button').addEvent('click', function(e) {
e.stop()
//do blabla 
});
```

This will stop the browser from jumping to the anchor, but I want to keep the anchor in the url so that one can share the link. I'm using the anchor actually for showing dynamic information.

Any ideas?

Comment: The way I usually handle this is to use values after the URL hash that do not match any name or id attributes on the page.  For example, "#myValue=foo" instead of "#foo".  If the hash value does match an element on the page I generally expect the window to scroll to that point.

Comment: Hey Jesse,
I ended up doing the same. I'm setting hashes like #!something
and then I just delete the ! when I want to use this hash for doing something on the page.

Answer (score 5):

Just immediately scroll back to the top of the page.

```
self.scrollTo(0, 0)
```

I had a plugin that did this and it happened so fast I just thought anchors were broken. I don't think anyone will notice.

Comment: Or what would be even more seamless would be to get the current scrollbar position for the window in the click handler and scroll back to that position instead of to the top.  That should work if you put the scrollTo() call in a setTimeout.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had a chance to test this cross-browser yet, so it might fail miserably in IE, but here's how I'm updating the URL with hash links while handling the actual action that occurs when clicking them differently (using the [HTML5 history API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)):

```
var setHash = function(hash) {
    // Make sure that the hash is the first character, and extract from (presumably) full URL if not
    if (hash.indexOf('#') > 0) {
        hash = hash.substr(hash.lastIndexOf('#'));
    } else if (hash.substr(0, 1) !== '#') {
        hash = '#' + hash;
    }
    // Add our hash element to the history/URL
    if (window.history.pushState) {
        window.history.pushState(null, null, hash);
    } else {
        window.location = hash;
    }
};

$('button').addEvent('click', function(e) {
    e.stop()
    setHash(this.get('href'));
    //do blabla 
});
```